# Memory leak, in do-catch block. iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am looking at memory leaks in my app that uses vision to detect text.

I am getting a memory leak which when using the tree points to this line:

```
try imageRequestHandler.perform([self.textDetectionRequest])
```

I am not sure why and hope someone can help with this.

Full code below.

```
private func performVisionRequest(image: CGImage, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        do {
            var imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, orientation: orientation, options: [:])
            try imageRequestHandler.perform([self.textDetectionRequest])
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to perform vision request: \(error)")

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the whole class:

```
import UIKit
import Vision

var noText: Bool!
var imageNo: UIImage!

internal class Slicer {

private var image = UIImage()
private var sliceCompletion: ((_ slices: [UIImage]) -> Void) = { _ in }

private lazy var textDetectionRequest: VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest = {

    return VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.handleDetectedText)
}()

internal func slice(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_: [UIImage]) -> Void)) {
    self.image = image
    self.sliceCompletion = completion
    self.performVisionRequest(image: image.cgImage!, orientation: .up)
}

// MARK: - Vision

private func performVisionRequest(image: CGImage, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        do {
            let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, orientation: orientation, options: [:])
            try imageRequestHandler.perform([self.textDetectionRequest])
        } catch let error as NSError {
            self.sliceCompletion([UIImage]())
            print("Failed to perform vision request: \(error)")

        }
    }
}

private func handleDetectedText(request: VNRequest?, error: Error?) {
    if let err = error as NSError? {
        print("Failed during detection: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    guard let results = request?.results as? [VNTextObservation], !results.isEmpty else {

        noText = true
        print("Tony no text found")
        var slices = [imageNo]
        self.sliceCompletion(slices as! [UIImage])
        slices = []
        return }

    noText = false
    self.sliceImage(text: results, onImageWithBounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.image.cgImage!.width, height: self.image.cgImage!.height))
}

private func sliceImage(text: [VNTextObservation], onImageWithBounds bounds: CGRect) {
    CATransaction.begin()

    var slices = [UIImage]()

    for wordObservation in text {
        let wordBox = boundingBox(forRegionOfInterest: wordObservation.boundingBox, withinImageBounds: bounds)

        if !wordBox.isNull {
            guard let slice = self.image.cgImage?.cropping(to: wordBox) else { continue }
            slices.append(UIImage(cgImage: slice))
        }
    }

    self.sliceCompletion(slices)

    CATransaction.commit()
}

private func boundingBox(forRegionOfInterest: CGRect, withinImageBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

    let imageWidth = bounds.width
    let imageHeight = bounds.height

    // Begin with input rect.
    var rect = forRegionOfInterest

    // Reposition origin.
    rect.origin.x *= imageWidth
    rect.origin.y = ((1 - rect.origin.y) * imageHeight) - (forRegionOfInterest.height * imageHeight)

    // Rescale normalized coordinates. Tony adde + 30 to increase the size of rect
    rect.size.width *= imageWidth + 30
    rect.size.height *= imageHeight + 30

    return rect
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is self.textDetectionRequest?

Comment: @SuhitPatil `lazy var textDetectionRequest: VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest = {
  return VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.handleDetectedText)  
 }()`

Comment: can you complete code for handleDetectedText as well.

Comment: `private func handleDetectedText(request: VNRequest?, error: Error?) {
  if let err = error as NSError? {
   print("Failed during detection: \(err.localizedDescription)")
   return
 }
  guard let results = request?.results as? [VNTextObservation], !results.isEmpty else {   
   noText = true
   print("Tony no text found")
   var slices = [imageNo]
   self.sliceCompletion(slices as! [UIImage])
   slices = []
   return }  
  noText = false
  self.sliceImage(text: results, onImageWithBounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.image.cgImage!.width, height: self.image.cgImage!.height))
 }`

Comment: of course @SuhitPatil

Comment: I have also added the whole class in my OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What everyone else is telling you is correct. You have two closures that refer to `self` (the Slicer) instance, and you need to break the retain cycle in both of them. I think this line is a huge mistake:

```
private lazy var textDetectionRequest: VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest = {
    return VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.handleDetectedText)
}()
```

You gain nothing by that, except for the retain cycle. Delete those lines! Instead, just create the anonymous function at the moment it is needed. Replace this:

```
try imageRequestHandler.perform([self.textDetectionRequest])
```

with this:

```
try imageRequestHandler.perform(
    [VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest(completionHandler:{ req, err in
        self.handleDetectedText(request:req, error:err)
    })]
)
```

If there is still a leak (which I doubt), then change it to

```
try imageRequestHandler.perform(
    [VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest(completionHandler:{ [weak self] req, err in
        self?.handleDetectedText(request:req, error:err)
    })]
)
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you for your time on this. This fixed the leak. Why does this work and not the other way? I would like to understand more. Again thank you for your time again, all the best. Tony

Comment: I don't know what "the other way" is. I merely summarized what everyone else was telling you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the way I had it with the leak.  You said you thought that  private lazy car was a mistake.

Comment: Well, it _is_ a mistake. You don't need it, and it is the very essence of a retain cycle. You (Slicer) are retaining an anonymous function (`textDetectionRequest`) which refers to you (`self`, Slicer) and is therefore retaining you. So you're retaining yourself. Bingo.

Comment: Ok excellent thank you for your time and explication on this. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [capture list](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) in your `textDetectionRequest` closure:

```
lazy var textDetectionRequest: VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest = 
         { [weak self] in
             return VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self?.handleDetectedText)
         }()
```

Comment: Thank you for yor answer @Carpsen90 But this gives me 4 errors saying i need to  seperate them with ;s and an unresolved identifier weak

Comment: @TonyMerritt maybe it's due to the `textDetectionRequest ` closure

Comment: Thank you for your time on this @Carpsen90, this seems to run with no errors but it looks like the leak then transfares to this area

Comment: I also added the whole class in the OP if that helps

Comment: @TonyMerritt I added `self?`, this should fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be something like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] _ in
    do {
        var imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, orientation: orientation, options: [:])
        try imageRequestHandler.perform([self?.textDetectionRequest])
    } catch let error as Error {
        print("Failed to perform vision request: \(error)")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `self.textDetectionRequest` is `lazy var` which captures the `handleDetectedText` which is a `closure` hence you should use capture list like `[unowned self]` or `[weak self]` to avoid retain cycle.

```
    private lazy var textDetectionRequest: VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest = { [unowned self] in
        return VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.handleDetectedText)
    }()
```

Plus you can pass the `VNRequest` array as dependency in `performVisionRequest` function simplify the code

```
    internal func slice(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping ((_: [UIImage]) -> Void)) {
        self.image = image
        self.sliceCompletion = completion
        let requests = self.textDetectionRequest
        self.performVisionRequest(image: image.cgImage!, orientation: .up, requests: [requests])
    }

    // MARK: - Vision

    private func performVisionRequest(image: CGImage, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation, requests: [VNRequest]) {

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            do {
                let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, orientation: orientation, options: [:])
                try imageRequestHandler.perform(requests)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                self.sliceCompletion([UIImage]())
                print("Failed to perform vision request: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the time on this i have implimented your sugestion, But i seem to still be getting some leak in that area. when using the memory graph to find it points to the same line `try imageRequestHandler.perform(requests)`